# mplayer - How can I detect EOF in Python

Tags: python, mplayer

I have a playlist that changes during play, Mplayer doesn't reload the playlist at the end of the first track so what I need to do is capture the EOF, then reload mplayer to carry on playing. How can I detect EOF using mplayer and popen? Or is there an easier way that I'm missing? I've checked the suggested 'duplicate' question and I don't believe it gives me the answer as this is capturing the end of a track/playlist via popen.

```
def play_music():
  global myplaylist
  global playflag
  if not playflag:
    mycommand = ["mplayer -really-quiet -slave -volume 1 -playlist /home/pi/scripts/playlist.txt"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(mycommand, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
   playflag = True
   else:
     pass
```

Comment: To clarify: when you run this procedure, you want to start mplayer with your playlist. Then something happens that changes (or appends to?) the file `playlist.txt`. When mplayer reaches the end of a track you want to rescan playlist.txt and if it has changed then you want to stop mplayer and restart with the new playlist. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly it, I have another procedure that adds new tracks to the `playlist.txt. I'd planned to use the `playflag` as a way of checking if mplayer was playing so I could trigger it but I can't find a way. So currently `play_music()` is called when a new track is added to the playlist and if it not running run the subprocess. HTH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I couldn't fix this issue, there must be a way of getting the mplayer status and then doing some code around the state. As it stands I couldn't get mplayer to reload the playlist once it had a new track added and when I did it started back at the beginning - Not very often I let something beat me!

For future readers I went down the MPD/MPC route, wasn't where I wanted to go but it has good playlist management and using the `client.consume` property it actually removes tracks from the playlist as you go which is great for a Jukebox scenario.

Comment: Nice choice of MDP. I would have simply ignored the builtin playlist of mplayer and "built my own": a queue/list of tracks where mplayer is restarted on the next track. roughly around the lines of `while len(tracks): track = tracks.pop(); shell(mplayer track); endwhile`

Comment: Thanks for that, will keep that in mind if I have any other issues.